# Linux does not detect internal storage when booting from an external drive

Tags: linux, boot, ssd

I'm using a Dell D11S machine, booting from the internal SSD works. If I boot from external storage (UEFI boot, Debian LVM on LUKS, SSD connected with an USB-SATA adapter), then the internal SSD is not detected by Linux.

> Output of lsblk:

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT  
sda                     8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk    
├─sda1                  8:1    0   142M  0 part  /boot/efi  
├─sda2                  8:2    0   620M  0 part  /boot  
└─sda3                  8:3    0 222.9G  0 part    
  └─sda3_crypt        253:0    0 222.9G  0 crypt   
    └─debian--vg-root 253:1    0 222.8G  0 lvm   /  
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I've checked the BIOS settings, but could not find anything that would indicate that this is the result of a security feature. The internal SSD has Debian installed, LVM on LUKS.

Comment: diff the output of `lsmod` when booting from internal and external - most likely you are not loading a driver.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be changing the settings in the BIOS. Setting the internal SSD to ACHI SATA mode instead of RAID (Intel Rapid Storage Technology) mode solved the problem.

Note: in my BIOS it was incorrectly named as Intel Rapid Restore Technology.